# estimation of variance of slope and intercept in logistic regression

Tags: probability, regression-analysis, standard-error

let us suppose we have following  data

[image]

i would like to test whether number of hours of studying  helps me to predict student will pass or not, i used following step, initially i give some values to slope and intercept

$\beta_1=0.1 $

$\beta_0=0.1$

after that i have calculated  $L$  as

$L=\beta_1 \cdot\text{Hours}+\beta_0 $

and also i have calculated probabilities  , all calculation is shown on screenshot

[image]

finally i have calculate sum of  last  calculated part and  i have got

```
-13.27734511
```

using  solver  i have estimated  slope and intercepts, also i have calculated estimated probabilities and  residuals
[image]

```
Slope       1.510731897
Intercept   -4.346648201
```

now i have  following questions

1. how to calculate  std error of intercepts and  slope ?
2. how to calculate P value  using  Wald test  ?

please give me hint and i will try to solve  myself

Comment: Nothing like Wald tests to make me feel I'm rusty in some things. A Wald test is a linear approximation used when an exact test is computationally expensive. The MLEs for slope and intercept in problems like this are found by iterative numerical methods. I'm guessing that at stats.stackexchange.com some of the regular posters know the answer to this one off the top of their heads. (And there's probably software that does this; I would actually be a bit surprised if it can't be done in R.) $\qquad$

Comment: then could you please migrate this question to  the stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: i am doing by excel because i want to calculate by hand and  learn

Comment: I've voted to migrate the question to stats.stackexchange.com . Apparently at least two other such votes are needed.